# refined selection of log-level of modules in Hydra

Tags: python, logging, fb-hydra

I'm trying to debug a `Hydra` application, setting `hydra.verbose=true` will set the logging level of all modules to `Debug`.
Is there a way to get rid of some of the modules debug messages that produce lengthy and non-informative Debug logs?
I can imagine a syntax like this: `hydra.verbose=~[NAME1,NAME2]`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality to deselect specific loggers.
You can either be additive and specify what you want to log as described [in the docs](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/logging/):

```
hydra.verbose=[NAME1,NAME2]: Sets the log level of the loggers NAME1 and NAME2 to DEBUG
```

(You will likely need to quote that to avoid shell confusion).

Or alternatively just define your own logging config and use that as described [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/logging/).

hydra/job_logging/my_custom_logging.yaml:

```yaml
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
root:
  handlers: [console]

# Log level for specific loggers:
loggers:
  __main__:
    level: INFO
  module.submodule:
    level: WARN
```

You can automatically use that config by default by overrindg the hydra/job_logging config group in your defaults list:
config.yaml:

```yaml
defaults:
  - override hydra/job_logging: my_custom_logging

foo: bar
# ...
```